# How to get information from my Frontend (Angular 2) in Spring Boot?

Tags: json, spring, angular, post, spring-boot

Well. I need create functions in my backend to communicate with my frontend. The method get to get information from my backend works fine. But I don't know how to read the json information in my backend.

This is my method get:

```
 @RequestMapping("/hi")
 public @ResponseBody String getName(){
    UserInfo info = new UserInfo("Lucas Alves",21,"luke@email.com","99998888");
    Gson g = new Gson();
    return g.toJson(info);
 }
```

I'm using the gson library to convert my object UserInfo to json string.

Now my question is. How I can get the json text send to me from the frontend and safe in a UserInfo.

Typescript code:

```
postUser(p: User){
   return this.http.post('http://localhost:8090/postUser', JSON.stringify(p), { headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) });
}
```

Java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/postUser"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createUser( What I need to have here? ) {
   //I Don't know what I need to do here.
}
```

Comment: you are sending json so, i think, it should go as `@RequestBody UserInfo input`, but if your js `User` is not 1 to 1 match you can create some DTO class

Answer (score 0):

You're on a good path.

You **could** implement a **User** class and then bind it directly:

```
public class User {

    private String username;

}
```

And your service

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/postUser"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createUser( @RequestBody User user ) {
    user.username; // use it?
}
```